# How to flatten char[][] into char[]?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a multidimensional char array:

```
board = new char[3][3];
```

in one of my classes to represent a tic tac toe game, and I have initialised it.

What would be the best way to flatten it into one array?

Comment: "I say this because i need to flatten it into one array" then your question should be about it from the start :) Allow me to edit it.

Answer (score 6):

```
int[][] x = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };

int [] flatten = Arrays.stream(x)
                       .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                       .toArray();
```

Using stream api this is rather simple.

In case you are using a `char [][]`:

```
char[][] board = {
            { 'x', 'o', ' ' },
            { ' ', 'o', 'x' },
            { ' ', 'o', 'x' },
};

StringBuilder sb = Arrays.stream(board)
            .flatMapToInt(x -> IntStream.range(0, x.length).map(i -> x[i]))
            .mapToObj(x -> (char) x)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append);

    char[] chars = new char[sb.length()];
    sb.getChars(0, sb.length(), chars, 0);
```

Comment: shouldn't this be dealing with `char[][]` instead of `int[][]`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of lists you can use `new String(char[] data)` to wrap each *row* into String object. Then you can join all strings and call `toCharArray` on final string.

Demo using streams added in Java 8

```
char[][] board = {
        {'x','o',' '},
        {' ','o','x'},
        {' ','o','x'},
};

char[] flatten = Arrays.stream(board)
                       .map(String::new)
                       .collect(Collectors.joining())
                       .toCharArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(flatten));
```

Output: `[x, o,  ,  , o, x,  , o, x]`.

---

But probably more efficient way would be manually creating `char[9]` and copying content of each "row" into it like

```
char[] flatten = new char[9];
int position = 0;
for (char[] row : board) {
    System.arraycopy(row, 0, flatten, position, row.length);
    position += row.length;
}
```

Comment: I guess your first example can be made more light weight by `String result = Arrays.stream(board)
                .flatMapToInt(x -> IntStream.range(0, x.length).map(i -> x[i]))
                .mapToObj(x -> (char) x)
                .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
                .toString();`

Comment: @Eugene You may be right, we would need to see what JIT will do with boxing each char to Character (I am not pro so I don't know JIT enough to discuss it). Anyway your solution feels... less intuitive (at least for me), so I would probably stay with what I have. If performance would be a problem I would probably use second solution from my answer :)

Comment: I totally agree on the readability side, I actually tried to come up with something more readable and could not

Comment: @Eugene Yes, having stream of primitive `char` type would make it a lot easier. Instead we are limited only to stream of `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best way flatten it into one array?

Slightly similar to one of @Pshemo's examples, but personally I'd go with.

```
Stream.of(board) 
      .map(String::valueOf)
      .collect(collectingAndThen(joining(), String::toCharArray));
```

You shouldn't need to worry about performance as this is not a heavy operation given you'll always have *three* arrays of which each only contains *three* elements.

---

imports required:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```